# Talend: matching 2 colomns and showing only rows where these values match

Tags: talend

I'm a beginner to Talend and I appreciate if someone can help me with this...

How to match the first 2 digits of a postal code ex: 69000 to another column containing the value 69. Then only show the rows where these values match. (Excel file with the full data attached)

Example of the data below:

```
ID, CompanyName, CodePostal, City, DepartementNumber, Region

5   TELMAT INFORMATIQUE 69000   LYON    66  pyrenees-orientales

5   TELMAT INFORMATIQUE 69000   LYON    67  bas-rhin

5   TELMAT INFORMATIQUE 69000   LYON    68  haut-rhin

**5 TELMAT INFORMATIQUE 69000   LYON    69  rhone**

5   TELMAT INFORMATIQUE 69000   LYON    70  haute-saone

5   TELMAT INFORMATIQUE 69000   LYON    71  saone-et-loire

5   TELMAT INFORMATIQUE 69000   LYON    72  sarthe

5   TELMAT INFORMATIQUE 69000   LYON    73  savoie
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please note that StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, but a place to help you with your code. Please include your own attempts and specify what doesn't work with them.

Comment: There is actually no code to poste, however my attempt was to add a filter in tMap coponent using stringHandling LEFT function to select the first 2 values of the string, then compare it using == operation with the 2 values from the second colomn.

Answer (score 0):

you can use REGEX :

https://help.talend.com/reader/JhYq1xxY0SNSBZCbOFzZGg/W8cU~47SzE__OIkoOg5JrA

```
^

Start of string, or start of line in a multi-line pattern

^Comment matches "Comment" at the beginning of the line.

^C.* matches the first line.
```

for example in mysql we have:

```
select * FROM companies WHERE CodePostal REGEXP '^(69)'
```

and in laravel we have:

```
->where('slug', 'regexp', "^(69)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple filter on the output of tMap, to let only the records which verify the condition:

```
StringHandling.LEFT(row.CodePostal, 2).equals(row.DepartementNumber)
```

You must use `equals` method on the String object, using == won't work.

Comment: Thanks iMezouar, your hint "You must use equals method on the String object, using == won't work." was actually solved the problem as I used this filter expression and it never worked using ==

Comment: Great! could you please accept the answer if it solved you problem ? :)